# Regex in MySql database

Tags: mysql, regex

sorry for my English.
Please help with pregex in MySql. I want to find two words in text. Between this words can be one or more spaces and/or punctuation mark.
 For example:
Tree, apple 
Tree   ,   apple 
Tree     ,apple 
Tree   ,apple 
Tree,apple 
Thanks you!

Comment: Welcome to SO... What did you try ? and what result did you get ?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL natively supports RegEx since 5.1. Are you looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `mycol` REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+[ ,.]*[[:alpha:]]+'
```

For more information, check out the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Given the examples in the post I would presume you should use `alpha` instead of `alnum`. It is also worth noting that `RLIKE` is a synonym for `REGEXP` and could be used as well, although I prefer `REGEXP` as the name better highlight the functionality of the operator.